# Weirdly slow Mysql Query on OR

Tags: mysql, sql, performance

I have the following query that takes 3 seconds

```
SELECT  SQL_NO_CACHE e.Id
    FROM  `Email` e
    LEFT JOIN  basedb.emailconnections ec  ON ec.id = e.EmailConnectionId
    LEFT JOIN  historydb.`event` ev  ON ev.EmailId = e.Id
    Where  e.UserId = 228
      OR  ev.PartnerId = 150
      AND  ev.Private = 0;
```

the problem comes from `(e.UserId = 228 OR ev.PartnerId = 150 AND ev.Private = 0)`

if I run only the left part from the WHERE like this, it takes 0.04 seconds

```
SELECT  SQL_NO_CACHE e.Id
    FROM  `Email` e
    LEFT JOIN  basedb.emailconnections ec  ON ec.id = e.EmailConnectionId
    LEFT JOIN  historydb.`event` ev  ON ev.EmailId = e.Id
    Where  e.UserId = 228;
```

and if I run the right part like this, it takes 0.03 seconds

```
SELECT  SQL_NO_CACHE e.Id
    FROM  `Email` e
    LEFT JOIN  basedb.emailconnections ec  ON ec.id = e.EmailConnectionId
    LEFT JOIN  historydb.`event` ev  ON ev.EmailId = e.Id
    Where  ev.PartnerId = 150
      AND  ev.Private = 0;
```

so it is way faster if I run 2 queries insted of running a single one and the result count from the two faster onces match the slow one

`SQL_NO_CACHE` is only for debuging

Comment: please qualify your condition to prevent ambiguity ( user OR ( partner and private ))  --OR-- (( user or partner ) and private).

Comment: After you've done that and it's still slow: It's legitimate to take two fast queries and use `UNION` to concatenate them. Sometimes it's better to avoid `OR`, because `OR` can make it difficult for the DB engine to select an index for the query.

Comment: show as the CREATE TABLE Query to see which Index are created

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- `AND` is usually faster than `OR`.
- The tests for one table will be used first, then it will "join" to the other table and filter by it.  This limits the efficiency of a `JOIN` and `WHERE`.
- Check this;

  ```
  Where  e.UserId = 228
    OR  ev.PartnerId = 150
    AND  ev.Private = 0;
  ```

is the same as

```
Where  e.UserId = 228
   OR  ( ev.PartnerId = 150  AND  ev.Private = 0 );
```

If that is not what you wanted, change the parentheses.

- These indexes may help with the first query (with the AND/OR parenthesised as stated):

  ```
  e:  INDEX(UserId, EmailConnectionId,  Id)
  ev:  INDEX(EmailId)
  ```
- As mentioned in the Comments, a `UNION` is often the way to speed up `OR`.

Comment: `UNION` did not help it way maybe 100ms faster but still over 3 seconds. adding `INDEX(UserId, EmailConnectionId,  Id)` helped to get it down to about 500ms. The other indeces were already present.